# Everything redirecting to https except homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

I have a WordPress blog hosted on digitalocean with vestapanel. Using let's encrypt ssl. Replaces WordPress address and site url with https in general settings. htacess file rule auto added:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http(s)?://)?(www\.)?example.com [NC]
```

Blog is non www preferred. Now everything is redirecting to https except the homepage (example.com).

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you clear your browser cookies and cache ?

Comment: Why are those RewriteConditions checking HTTP_REFERER instead of SERVER_PORT?